# Permission denied in accessing Opencart folder installed in a Centos OS

Tags: centos, opencart

I have a problem with my installation in Centos. The problem is I can't access my front end page. If I open the front end there's only a blank page. But the admin part is ok. I already change the permission to `777`.

These are the `catalog, admin, download, image, system and vqmod`.

I already checked the database connections and it is working in the admin part.

I don't know where did I go wrong.

If I navigate the folder like image. I got this error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /image/ on this server.

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at giftregistrys3.metro.com.ph Port 80
```

I think the reason are the permissions. But I already change the permissions.. :(

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Guys I enabled the error and I got this>
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv() in /data/APACHE/html/metro/system/library/encryption.php on line 8
Should I need to install this module?

Comment: Yes you need to install Mcrypt

Comment: I already installed that and I already restarted the apache. But still I got this error

Comment: Should I need to enable it in the php.ini configuration?

Comment: Of course. Just installing is not enough, you need to enable it :-)